# Reducer is recieving parameters but is doing nothing ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, redux

This is my reducer :

```
case action.DELETE_COMMENT:
        return {
            ...state ,
            comments : comments.filter((item : any) => item.commentid !== action.id)
        }
```

It is recieving id correctly but in Redux dev tools I'm getting state is equals which means it is not deleting anything,
Could you guys help me please?

```
  const deleteComment = (id : Number) => {
    axios.delete(`http://localhost:4000/deleteComment/${id}`,)
        .then((res) => {
            dispatch(actions.deleteComment(id))
        })
        .catch((err) => {
            console.log('--------err', err);
        })
}
```

Here is how i m passing id :

```
<ul>
                        {
                            comments.map((items: any) => {
                                return (
                                    <p
                                        key={uuidv4()}
                                    >Comment : {items.comment}
                                    <button onClick={() => {deleteComment(items.commentid)}}>Delete</button>
                                    </p>
                                );
                            })}
                    </ul>
```

And this part works id is passing correctly
I also checked and my store `comments` is not empty

Comment: Seems like the problem is with the filter statement. This might help `comments.filter((item) => item.commentid != action.id)` Also, I feel that the delete operation should be performed at the server end and not taken care of by React/Redux

Comment: nope,same result

Comment: If you have a server which will actually delete it, then I think it'll be better if you get the set of comments again and render it afresh. But if you wish to continue the same approach, then maybe you should try sharing a repo link with the question so that we can look into the code.

Comment: I thought about that way,But wouldnt server crash when lets say 10000 users will press delete?

Comment: It would send 20k requests (delete and get) at the same time and i thought it was bad approach

Comment: It will not, cause the server should be scalable. Also, the approach you're taking is actually not deleting it from the database, which serves no purpose than to fool the user.

Comment: comments : comments.filter((item : any) => item.commentid !== action.id)

in above line, where is comments defined?? you are applying filter on it right.

Comment: its defined in state